# Counting maximum k-mer repetition frequency

Tags: python, string, sequence

If n is 3, then the sequence "ATATATATAG" contains 4x "ATA", 3x "TAT" and 1x "TAG". The proportion is thus 4/8=0.5. The higher this number, the more repetitive the sequence.

Write a function `simple(s,n)` where `s` is a sequence and `n` is the length of the k-mer to consider. The function should return the proportion described above.

Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: You probably want to use a for loop to go from start to end of the input string. Keep a python dictionary of each sequence of length n=3 that you encounter in the input sequence.

Comment: Can you post what you have already done or even your own thoughts on how you plan to approach the problem?
This is not a homework service.

Answer (score 1):

```
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter


def simple(seq, n):
    return Counter(ngrams(seq, n)).most_common(1)[0][1] / float(len(seq) - n + 1)
```

Comment: Nice golfing :)

Comment: Why import a 3rd party library?  `seq[i:i+n] for i in range(len(seq) - n + 1)` will yield the same generator over ngrams.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, but at least it's the brainteaser kind.

Hint: `itertools`, `generators`, and `collections` are very handy for problems like these.

```
import itertools
import collections

ACIDS = ('A', 'C', 'T', 'G')


def walk_seq(s, chunk_size):
    assert len(s) >= chunk_size
    for i in range(0, len(s) - chunk_size + 1):
        yield s[i:i+chunk_size]


def simple(s, n):
    snip_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for chunk in walk_seq(s, n):
        for snip_tuple in itertools.product(ACIDS, repeat=n):
            snip = ''.join(snip_tuple)
            if chunk == snip:
                snip_counts[snip] += 1
    total_matches = sum(snip_counts.values())
    maxi = max(snip_counts.values())
    return float(maxi) / total_matches

print simple('ATATATATAG', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good algorithms question, try it yourself too, but here is the solution with little challenge.

```
s = "ATATATATAG"
n = 3

def simple(s,n):
    dictionary = {}
    total = 0
    for i in range (len(s)-(n-1)): # (n-1) to get last element
        k = i+n
        if s[i:k] in dictionary:
            dictionary[s[i:k]] += 1
        else:
            dictionary.update({s[i:k]:1})
        total += 1 # doing it here to avoid sum(dictionary.values())

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[key] = value/total
    # As a challenge, edit the line above to lambda function
    print(dictionary)

simple(s,n)

# sample output
#{'TAT': 0.375, 'ATA': 0.5, 'TAG': 0.125}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples as that, using the defaultdict from collections and a for loop:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> def kmer_counter(seq, k):
...     kmers = defaultdict(int)
...     for i in range(len(seq) - k + 1):
...         kmer = seq[i:i+k]
...         kmers[kmer] = kmers.get(kmer, 0) + 1
...     return kmers
... 
>>> s = "ATATATATAG"
>>> n = 3
>>> kmer_counter(s, n)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'ATA': 4, 'TAT': 3, 'TAG': 1})
```